# Delete element in DataFrame under condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

my DataFrame is looking at this :

```
indeed.fr
11.41%
career2.successfactors.eu
8.53%
37.16%
pracuj.pl
7.40%
80.42%
corporate.danone.com.br
6.64%
indeed.com.br
4.68%
61.73%
```

Thus I want to only conserve the first % as follows :

```
indeed.fr
11.41%
career2.successfactors.eu
8.53%
pracuj.pl
7.40%
corporate.danone.com.br
6.64%
indeed.com.br
4.68%
```

All rows are string and so on I don't know if we can delete rows under condition such as the previous row contains % ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your time !

```
mydata =['indeed.fr','11.41%','career2.successfactors.eu','8.53%','37.16%','pracuj.pl','7.40%','80.42%','corporate.danone.com.br','6.64%','indeed.com.br','4.68%','61.73%']
df=pd.DataFrame(mydata)
```

At the end, I want this : [image: My need]

Comment: Post the code you used to create the DataFrame. If you read it from a CSV, at least format it in a way that we can see rows and columns.

Comment: I publish "my way" to create it, obviously it's not really as it. It's coming from an html webpage code and so on it's never the same data

Comment: Alright, is `37.16%` in the second row of the column `career2.successfactors.eu`, `80.42%` in second row of the column `pracuj.pl` and `61.73%` in the second row of column `indeed.com.br`?

Comment: You would easily have an answer from people by now if you could give a better idea about the structure.

Comment: It's just one column for the moment, but at the end I will make it with 2 columns that's why I need to have only one % in order to fractionate it each 2 raws. In the first column the name and the second the value in %. The second % is the variation but I don't need it because it's not given every time ..

Comment: Alright. I understand the problem now. I will come up with a solution

Comment: Done! Let me know if my solution works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydata =['indeed.fr','11.41%','career2.successfactors.eu','8.53%','37.16%','pracuj.pl','7.40%','80.42%','corporate.danone.com.br','6.64%','indeed.com.br','4.68%','61.73%']

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
```

Was the sample you created.

The solution is below

```
rowList = []
row = []

#Variable to keep track of the number of times I see the percentage value
percentVal = 0

for i in df.index:


    if(df.at[i, 0][0] not in set('0123456789')):


        row.append(df.at[i, 0])

        percentVal = 0

    else:


        percentVal += 1

        if(percentVal != 2):
            row.append(df.at[i, 0])
            rowList.append(row)
            row = []

        else:
            #If percentVal == 2, that means, I have seen my second percentage value and I'm going to skip it.
            print("Skipping {}".format(df.at[i, 0]))
            row = []



yourSol = pd.DataFrame(rowList)
yourSol.columns = ['Incoming Referal Sources', 'Value (%)']

print(yourSol)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it's working well, just adding the init of **row** :) Thanks again :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Always know that, if you post a reproducible example like the line you added to create the DataFrame, it makes life much easier in understanding and people would get right ahead with the solution and you will save a lot of time.

Comment: Hey again, I have just a problem when it's not abcdefghi... I have Arabic or Chinese or Russian letters too

Comment: @AlexGermain Sorry! I had gone for a walk. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: It's perfect !! Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: @AlexGermain You can also UPVOTE my answer if you're happy.